# Entity Framework - Best pattern to change connection string and retry on password failure (EF 6)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework with AWS Secrets Manager. The password to the database can be rotated anytime. The password will become stale, automatically after a fixed period Or can also be manually rotated.

My Context :

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{

    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TestDto> TestDtoData { get; set; }

}
```

DI Registration:

```
services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options =>
            {
                var connectionString = getConnectionStringAsync().Result;
 
                options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
             });
```

Used Like:

```
private readonly TestDbContext _intentDbContext;

public ProductIntentManager(TestDbContext testDbContext)
{
    _testDbContext = testDbContext;
}

public List<TestDto> GetAll()
{
    try
    {
        return _testDbContext.TestDtoData.ToList();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Connection Exception - When Database credentials change 
        // Don't want to include retry logic here, want it to be in a single place
        var a = e;
        throw;
    }
}
```

What is the best pattern, to retry the query after changing the connection string ?

(New connection string should be use for subsequent requests)

Edit : Looking to achieve this by not having to replicate code (add retry logic in call try/catch blocks), or creating a wrapper class, that opens or closes the connection.
Any clean solution maybe using interceptors or retry policy is what I am looking for.

Comment: Side note: avoid using `.Result`, use an async lamba. That said, you probably want to register a [context factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor) rather than a context and get the connection string "just in time" in its `CreateDbContext()` method.

Comment: Not sure how CreateDbContext() helps, AddDbContext is injected as a scoped service. Which means that connection string is evaluated Just in time as well. But I cant hit the async service (AWS Secret Manager) to retrieve the connection string everytime. We use some caching that refreshes it in 1 day or so.

Comment: In that case I guess you should validate & change the connection in the middleware. You can't do that in every method that opens a connection. But this question is pretty opinion-based.

Comment: Opening and closing in the middleware, would mean I am keeping the connection a lot longer than required. The actual code between the middleware, could have other async calls that it waits for. I want this wrapped up inside the Data Layer itself.

Comment: Any opinion will do, am still looking to find any good implementation for this, that does not require me to either create a wrapping class or replicate my code. With those constrains, based on what we have, it should be a pretty narrow space to find a solution